# Text in published article on front page not showing

Tags: 7, nodes

I have no idea what happened (I had to reupload the site and am working on putting all the data back up), but I cannot get the trimmed version of my article appear in the content block on the front page (see screenshot).

I have tried all options in the manage field and manage display I think, and the only time text is shown is when I opt that the entire article is shown on the front page--which is not acceptable. I have put the break tag in and out of the body text too, so I'm rather desperate now for an answer (mostly because I was supposed to launch the site 2 hours ago and all I've done for the past 4 hours was trying to regain data haha--but that's got nothing to do with my current question...)

I hope someone can shine some bright light so I can solve this. Thanks in advance! :)
Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: did you check Drupal logs?

Comment: How do I do that? :)

Comment: Go to admin -> reports -> recent log messages  or use this path `admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: Thank you for that. I just don't know what to look at / do with it? :)

Comment: You need to look if there's any error or notice that might preventing article text to be displayed. Errors marked in red and x icon, you might find a lot of them. You have post the right error message so we can help you.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand, thank you for explaining! No, there are no error messages at all with the article, probably sadly, or you might be able to help me quicker. :)

Comment: When you edit the content type and manage fields, what are the settings for teaser? (I assume you're using teaser as the view mode for the blog...)

Comment: Did you copy your site from another server? if so check PHP settings/configuration and compare it with previous server

Comment: I copied it from the same server--it was supposed to go to another subdomain. I have no idea how to check the PHP settings/configurations?

Comment: Solved! I don't know how--at the time I had been working on it for 11 hours so I wasn't in the state of mind to back track--I was just happy it worked. Thanks for helping. :D